# jquery datatable display format

Tags: jquery, html

i am using jquery data table and i need to display the titles in different rows.
example:

```
                "aoColumns" : [
                {'sTitle' : 'SI Number' },
                {'sTitle' : 'user'},
                {'sTitle' : 'Status'}
                ]
```

so it will display the table in the following format..

```
            **SI Number    user    Status**
```

But i need to print in the following format.

```
           SI Number      ****  ****

           User          *****    ****

           Status        *****    ****
```

Is it possible to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var aoColumns = [{'sTitle' : 'SI Number' },{'sTitle' : 'user'},{'sTitle' : 'Status'}];
$(aoColumns).each(function(){
    console.log($(this)[0].sTitle+"       ****      *****");
});
```

Check the the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ceat/

Comment: by the way the *** means the data which am actually reading from a dictionary..  basically instead of printing the data in row wise i need to print in coloumn.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that if you use jquery datatables, that you doesn't provide any API for you to do this.